# How to compile <linnux/kernel.h> in Linux gcc compiler?

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel

I have a simple question. I want to compile the following c file:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

extern void *sys_call_table[];


asmlinkage int (*original_sys_open)(int);

asmlinkage int our_fake_open_function(int error_code)
{

        /*print message on console every time we
 *          *are called*/
        printk("HEY! sys_open called with error_code=%d\n",error_code);

        /*call the original sys_exit*/
        return original_sys_open(error_code);
}

/*this function is called when the module is
*  *loaded (initialization)*/
int init_module()
{
        /*store reference to the original sys_exit*/
        original_sys_open=sys_call_table[__NR_open];

        /*manipulate sys_call_table to call our
 *          *fake exit function instead
 *                   *of sys_exit*/
        sys_call_table[__NR_open]=our_fake_open_function;
}


/*this function is called when the module is
 *  *unloaded*/
void cleanup_module()
{

        /*make __NR_exit point to the original
 *          *sys_exit when our module
 *                   *is unloaded*/
        sys_call_table[__NR_open]=original_sys_open;

}
```

The problem is that gcc -I/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64/include myfile.c generates a unsolvabe include dependency  which can be found in .
  Please tell me how to fix this gcc compiler problem I am encountering today. Thank you very much for your insight.

Comment: This code will not work because the system call table is neither exported nor writable, and the `open` parameters are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to build external modules is documented in [the documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt):

> ```
> $ make -C <path_to_kernel_src> M=$PWD
> ```